# 80% favors the building of a leisure center. Find the probability that the 7th Person is the 2nd person who is not in favor of the leisure centre.

Tags: geometric-probability

For this question, I know I need to use Geometric Distribution. But I am lost because question asked for the 2nd person i.e 2nd occurrence instead of 1st occurrence. Appreciate anyone's help. Thanks!

Comment: We may search for a very similar exercice : Question 1 : We ask 6 persons, what is the probability to have exactly 1 person in favor of this leisure center ? Question 2 : what is the probability that person n°7 is in favor of this leisure center ? Question 3 : your initial question.

Comment: See [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$  You need that exactly $~1~$ of the first $~6~$ people is not in favor, and that the $~7$-th person, specifically, is also not in favor of it.

Comment: This is more like the [Negative Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#:~:text=In%20probability%20theory%20and%20statistics,of%20successes%20(denoted%20)%20occurs.). You need $\mathbb P(NB(2,0.2)) = 7$, because you're looking for the second occurrence and the probability of one occurrence is $0.2$.

Comment: Hint: In order for the 7th person to be the 2nd not in favor, we must have (1) exactly one "not in favor" person among the first 6 people, and (2) the 7th person is not in favor.